# Extracting the post body from an HTTP response

Tags: java, apache, http, get, httprequest

I am trying to use httpClient (by apache) to post and get data. Posting is absolutely fine and my code for that has no issues, however, I cannot say the same for getting data.

The website I am trying to get data from is this: http://www.posttestserver.com/data/2013/04/16/01.13.04594755373

I only want to receive the body of the post (i.e. the JSON string at the bottom starting with Recent Cases), however, the method I am currently using (and every method I find online) returns the time, source IP, headers and body (basically it returns everything). Is there anyway to parse the body of out this? I don't want to go through the returned string and tell it to look for the text "Begin Post Body", I want a natural method for doing this. Does that exist?

TLDR: I only want it to return what's in the post body

Here's my code:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.posttestserver.com/data/2013/04/16/01.41.38521171013");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));

}
```

And here's what is returned:

```
Time: Tue, 16 Apr 13 01:41:38 -0700
Source ip: 155.198.108.247

Headers (Some may be inserted by server)
UNIQUE_ID = UW0OwtBx6hIAACfjfl4AAAAA
CONTENT_LENGTH = 7627
CONTENT_TYPE = application/json
HTTP_HOST = posttestserver.com
HTTP_CONNECTION = close
HTTP_USER_AGENT = Apache-HttpClient/4.2.4 (java 1.5)
REMOTE_ADDR = 155.198.108.247
REMOTE_PORT = 54779
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = CGI/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD = POST
QUERY_STRING = 
REQUEST_URI = /post.php
REQUEST_TIME = 1366101698

No Post Params.

== Begin post body ==
{"Recent Cases":[{"descript..etc etc"}]}
== End post body ==
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the following method a url and it will give you the response in a String without any header details, so in your example just the json.

```
private static String readUrl(final String urlString) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            final URL url = new URL(urlString);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            int read;
            final char[] chars = new char[1024];
            while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1) {
                buffer.append(chars, 0, read);
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but your method produces the exact same output as mine (your buffer.toString() produces the same as my EntityUtils.toString(entity) ). =S. Any other advice?

Comment: Ah, I see that's the response from the url that appears in a browser too so it's not the actual header it's the entire page! That response is invalid JSON.  If they don't have a restful url you an parse that just produces the JSON you might be screwed and will have to String parse it (which is horrible).

Comment: I changed the upload to JSON and have the same error, which means String parsing is likely. Ugh. Really had hoped there would be a more elegant solution. Thanks anyway d99w.